# Form input does not show up in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, input

When I submit the following code, the only thing that goes into my database is the second select section (49/43). The other inputs are written into the database with the value "0", no matter what input I submit. I would be very grateful for some help!

```
<?php 
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX' );

    if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( sex, pre, nmbr) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['sex'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pre'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nmbr'])}' )";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ( $insert ) {
        echo "Sucess!";
    } else {
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli_error}");
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

?>

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <select name="sex">
            <option>W</option>
            <option>M</option>
        </select>
        <select name="pre">
          <option>+49</option>
          <option>+43</option>
         </select>

        <input name"nmbr" type="text" placeholder=" Deine Handynummer hier eingeben">
        <button> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </form>
```

Comment: `$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['sex'])` Transfer these codes inside a variables. Bad practice of programming.

Comment: I'm not really into coding, and I did use a tutorial :|

Comment: The complex variable expressions are perfectly fine (not the most convenient approach, but more workable than line-wise escaping). -- Use `print_r($_POST);` to see if you actually received the correct form input. Tell us about the table schema.

Comment: whats the field types in the db?

Comment: "sex" is a reserved word. Oops, my bad, it's "set".

Comment: BTW: the types of the colums in the database are INT. Maybe it has something to do with the problem?

Comment: Okay, so the table shema is: 
3 colums -> (1) sex (2) pre (3) nmbr

Comment: Array ( [sex] => W [pre] => +49 ) is the print_r output

Comment: **W** is not an **INT**, well not the last time i checked

Comment: Try changing the types of sex and pre to `varchar`

Comment: Sidenote: since you're obviously using everything inside the same file, you need to use `isset()` and/or `!empty()` against all your POST arrays.

Comment: *"BTW: the types of the colums in the database are INT. Maybe it has something to do with the problem?"* - Errr... ummmm. yeah; **big time**. That's like trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. However, Peg was never square.

Comment: sex and pre are working fine now - thx!

Comment: but there is still the problem that print_r($_POST) just shows the input of sex and pre. It seems there is no input at all in the input field no matter what I'm writing into the field. Why isnt the input field part of the input array?

Comment: Have a real close look at that input again.... real close. Zoom in **10x** if you have to ;-) pretty obvious syntax error.

Comment: there you go. and you're welcome, *cheers* - *"shit happens"* - we've all been there, or others will follow. I just want to make sure I've a good pair of thick rubber boots.

Comment: Just look into your code 10 times or maybe a hundred times. If you can't see it. Drink coffee and try it again. :D

Comment: what to do about the question now... leave it in limbo, post an answer, delete? those are the questions @DavidLux

Comment: I'll answer it for fellow rookies!

Comment: You have the floor @DavidLux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comment section, this works just fine now.

Additional info: The column types in the database are VARCHAR for "sex" and "pre" as well as INT for the "nmbr" input. Another sidenote from the comment section: "since you're obviously using everything inside the same file, you need to use isset() and/or !empty() against all your POST arrays."

```
<?php 
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {



    $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX' );

    if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
        die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( sex, pre, nmbr) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['sex'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pre'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nmbr'])}' )";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ( $insert ) {
        echo "Success!";

    } else {
        die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli_error}");
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

?>

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <select name="sex">
            <option>W</option>
            <option>M</option>
        </select>
        <select name="pre">
          <option>+49</option>
          <option>+43</option>
         </select>

        <input name="nmbr" type="text" placeholder=" Deine Handynummer hier eingeben">
        <button> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </form>
```